# Saving UIImage created from CGImage to Saved Photos album crashes my app

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to implement uncompressed photos in a little practice app of mine, but I can't get it to work for the life of me.

This is how I capture a photo:

```
print("Shutter!")
if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
    stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
        (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

        if let cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageDataSampleBuffer) {
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0)
            let rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame)
            let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame)
            let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame)
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0)

            let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, rawImageBytes, width * height * 4, nil)
            let bitsPerComponent = 8
            let bitsPerPixel = 32
            let colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            let bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo = .ByteOrderDefault
            let renderingIntent: CGColorRenderingIntent = .RenderingIntentDefault

            if let imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow * 4, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, false, renderingIntent) {
                print("Attempting to save image")
                let tiffImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(tiffImage, nil, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
            } else {
                print("CGImageCreate failed")
            }
        } else {
            print("CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Executing that chunk of code prints "Shutter!" and "Attempting to save image" to Xcode's output panel, then crashes the app, causing Xcode to show me a bunch of what I think is Assembly code. Needless to say, this doesn't help me at all.

I have tried displaying the UIImage in a UIImageView, which also caused the app to crash. What's going on here?

Comment: What line you get the crash?

Comment: On the line with the call to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum().

Comment: can you put `nil` for `"image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"`?

Comment: For some reason, the app stopped crashing. The image doesn't get saved regardless. Replacing the abovementioned selector with nil makes no difference at all.